# Is it necessary to deregister a socket from epoll before closing it?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

Assume the following code where "sock" is a handle to TCP socket that was previously registered with an epoll file descriptor designated by epfd.

```
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, sock, &ev);
close(sock);
```

Is it still necessary to call epoll_ctl if the socket is going to get subsequently closed anyway? Or does the socket get implicitly deregistered as a result of closing it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [man page](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html):

> **Q6**  Will closing a file descriptor cause it to be removed from all epoll sets
>      automatically?
>
> **A6**  Yes, but be aware of the following point.  A file descriptor is a
>      reference to an open file description (see `open`(2)).  Whenever a
>      descriptor is duplicated via `dup`(2), `dup2`(2), `fcntl`(2) `F_DUPFD`, or
>      `fork`(2), a new file descriptor referring to the same open file description
>      is created.  An open file description continues to exist until all file
>      descriptors referring to it have been closed.  A file descriptor is
>      removed from an `epoll` set only after all the file descriptors referring to
>      the underlying open file description have been closed (or before if the
>      descriptor is explicitly removed using `epoll_ctl`(2) `EPOLL_CTL_DEL`).  This
>      means that even after a file descriptor that is part of an `epoll` set has
>      been closed, events may be reported for that file descriptor if other file
>      descriptors referring to the same underlying file description remain open.

Comment: Thanks! I kept doing "man epoll_ctl", "man epoll_create" looking for an answer, but forgot about the summary man page for "man epoll".

Comment: So provided nobody has duplicated it with dup() and the process hasn't forked, you're ok?

Comment: Yes, I think that sums it nicely.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case, however. I just wrote a simple snippet that created a listening socket, added it to an epoll, closed the socket and went on to epoll_wait. It was there, it fired if a con had been made in between and del succeeded.

Comment: I think the desired behaviour is that it should be removed.  But I'm seeing that if you do a half shutdown it won't be removed.  Beware of that.  It makes sense that a half shutdown won't remove it.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, obviously file descriptors don't close if you don't `close()` them...

Comment: @TommiKyntola: just to clarify, you were expecting that a close() will remove the event that was already added to the queue?