# c++ socket accept() get Resource deadlock avoided errno with epoll

Tags: c++, sockets, epoll

I'm a C++ beginner learning I/O multiplexing.

Here is my code:

`test.cpp` (**doesn't use `epoll()`** and works well):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    char buffer[1024];
    buffer[0] = 'f';
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    int serverFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    // bind & listen
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    int bindResult = bind(serverFd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (bindResult < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to bind\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int listenResult = listen(serverFd, 1024);
    if (listenResult < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to listen\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr clientAddr;
    unsigned int clientlen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    int acceptFd = accept(serverFd, &clientAddr, &clientlen);
    if (acceptFd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to create client connection file descriptor\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int fd = acceptFd;
    ssize_t received = recv(fd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
    if (received < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to received bytess from client\n");
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EINTR\n");
        } else if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK\n");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Reason: %d\n", errno);
            close(fd);
            return 1;
        }
    } else if (received == 0) {
        close(fd);
    } else {
        buffer[received] = '\0';
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

`test_2.cpp` (**does use `epoll()`** and doesn't work well):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    // TODO: too much error message to handle, so it's necessary to deal with it (maybe macros can)
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    // process ignore SIGPIPE which is caused by send(), or process will exit, which is hard to find out
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    // here needs a socket fd or other fd
    // well, AF_INET is okay;socket(PF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0) is sctp, tcp cannot use SOCK_SEQPACKET :(
    // when using tcp, watch out **record boundaries**
    int serverFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (serverFd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to create socket file descriptor\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // nonblock
    // nonblock
    int flags = fcntl(serverFd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to get flags\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int setFlagResult = fcntl(serverFd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (setFlagResult < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to set flags\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // bind & listen
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    int bindResult = bind(serverFd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (bindResult < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to bind\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int listenResult = listen(serverFd, 1024);
    if (listenResult < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to listen\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // epoll fd
    int epollFd = epoll_create(1);
    if (epollFd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to create epoll file descriptor\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // event
    struct epoll_event event, events[1024];
    event.events = EPOLLIN;
    event.data.fd = serverFd;
    // ctl
    int ctlResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, serverFd, &event);
    if (ctlResult < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // wait
    while (1) {
        int event_count = epoll_wait(epollFd, events, 1024, -1);

        for (int i = 0; i < event_count; i++) {
            struct epoll_event event = events[i];
            // accept
            if (event.data.fd == serverFd) {
                unsigned int clientlen = sizeof(clientAddr);
                int acceptFd = accept(serverFd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &clientlen);
                if (acceptFd < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to create client connection file descriptor\n");
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail Reason: %d\n", errno);
                    return 1;
                }

                // nonblock
                int flags = fcntl(acceptFd, F_GETFL, 0);
                if (flags < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to get flags\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                int setFlagResult = fcntl(acceptFd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
                if (setFlagResult < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to set flags\n");
                    return 1;
                }

                struct epoll_event event;
                event.events = EPOLLIN;
                event.data.fd = serverFd;
                int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, acceptFd, &event);
                if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                // client recv
            } else if (event.events & EPOLLIN) {
                int fd = event.data.fd;
                char buffer[1024+1];
                ssize_t received = recv(fd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
                if (received < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to received bytess from client\n");
                    if (errno == EINTR) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EINTR\n");
                    } else if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK\n");
                    } else {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Reason: %d\n", errno);
                        close(fd);
                        int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, &event);
                        if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else if (received == 0) {
                    int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, &event);
                    if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                    close(fd);
                } else {
                    buffer[received] = '\0';
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
                    // if you want to send something...
                    event.events |= EPOLLOUT;
                    // here is some data that event can hold
                    event.data.u32 = (uint32_t) 1;
                    // you can now send data or just put event in epoll, which is maybe easier
                    int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &event);
                    if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                // client send
            }  else if (event.events & EPOLLOUT) {
                int fd = event.data.fd;
                char buffer[] = "I see you";
                ssize_t sendResult = send(fd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
                if (sendResult < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to received bytess from client\n");
                    if (errno == EINTR) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EINTR\n");
                    } else if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK\n");
                    } else {
                        if (errno == EPIPE) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Reason: EPIPE\n");
                        } else {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Reason: %d\n", errno);
                        }
                        close(fd);
                        int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, &event);
                        if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else if (sendResult == 0) {
                    event.events = EPOLLIN;
                    int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &event);
                    if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else {

                    // if you want to recv something...
//                    event.events |= EPOLLIN;
//                    // you can now send data or just put event in epoll, which is maybe easier
//                    int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &event);
//                    if (ctlClientResult < 0) {
//                        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to run epoll_ctl\n");
//                        return 1;
//                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to make a TCP socket connection (such as `curl -v "http://host:80/"`, which can make `test2.cpp` run in *line 81*), `acceptFd` is `< 0` and `errno` is `11` according to *line 84*, which means "Resource deadlock avoided".

Why? There isn't any thread-related code, is it?

Comment: "_Here is my code_" All information relevant to the question, including [mcve], must be present in the question itself, and not be hidden behind external links.

Comment: Your code belongs in the question as text, not at an external link that can go bad. [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I will pay attention to how to ask this kind of question in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 11 is `EAGAIN`, which is a very common error code to encounter when dealing with non-blocking socket I/O. It means the requested operation has nothing to do, try it again later.

In the case of [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html), it means:

> `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`
>
> The socket is marked nonblocking and **no connections are present to be accepted**. POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 allow either error to be returned for this case, and do not require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities.

This means you are calling `accept()` at the wrong time, when the listening socket does not have any clients to accept. Double check your `epoll()` usage, it likely has a logic bug in it that is causing you to call `accept()` prematurely.

For instance, after `accept()` has successfully accepted a client, you are assigning the **listening** socket instead of the **client** socket to `event.data.fd` when calling `epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_ADD)`:

```
struct epoll_event event;
event.events = EPOLLIN;
event.data.fd = serverFd; // <-- HERE, SHOULD BE acceptFd INSTEAD!
int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, acceptFd, &event);
```

As such, when the **client** has data waiting to be read, your loop will end up calling `accept()` on the **listening** socket instead of calling `recv()` on the **client** socket.

Also, you are not checking the reported `event.events` field for socket errors.  If an error occurs on a client socket, the reported `events` may include the `EPOLLERR` and/or `EPOLLHUP` flags.  You should check for those flags and if present then close the client socket, before checking for the `EPOLLIN` flag to call `recv()`.

Also, note that in your example, [it is not necessary to call `epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_DEL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707601/)  before calling `close()` on a socket.  Closing a socket file descriptor will automatically remove it from the epoll instance that is monitoring it.

Comment: Thanks! I changed serverFd to acceptFd and I can recv client bytes(but a new bug occured... when I tried to send "I see you" I got errno == 88, which is "Socket operation on non-socket"); Also, I handled EPOLLERR and EPOLLHUP, and I deleted call epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_DEL) Thank you:)

Comment: After I commented `event.data.u32 = (uint32_t) 1;` all works well, which is confused me...

Comment: @ShiroSora that is because `event.data` is a `union` of multiple values. Setting its `u32` field **overwrites** its `fd` field. That is why you end up passing an invalid socket descriptor to `send()`

Comment: That's right! I thought **wrongly** that `event.data` is `struct`...

Answer (score 1):

```
            struct epoll_event event;
            event.events = EPOLLIN;
            event.data.fd = serverFd;
            int ctlClientResult = epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, acceptFd, &event);
```

When you add the newly-accepted connection to the epoll set, you tell it to report it as a hit on `serverFd`. So when the client sends you data, you try to accept a new connection instead.

Change `event.data.fd = serverFd` to `event.data.fd = acceptFd`.

Then you can move on to your next bug:

```
            char buffer[] = "I see you";
            ssize_t sendResult = send(fd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
```

1024?!

Also, any time you use non-blocking sockets, you should add code to handle `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` errors as non-fatal.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed these bug and it worked well partly :)